# socket.io - ReferenceError: io is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, ios, socket.io, referenceerror

I am writing an application for Android 2.3.5 (that will also be compatible with iOS). I wish to transfer data from the app's HTML/Javascript to a Python program on a server (which uses the Twisted engine to retrieve the data).

I've tried many things and looked at various forums, answers, tutorials, and web pages--including most of them here--and can't find an answer. Here's the relevant Javascript I have in my index.html file:

```
<script src="socket-lib/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function sendData() {
    try {
        var socket = io.connect('http://mywebsite.com:12345');
        socket.on('connect', function(data) {
            socket.send('Hello.');
            socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                socket.send('This is where I send data?');
            });
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert('ERROR: socket.io encountered a problem:\n\n' + err);
    }
} // end of sendData
```

If you can't tell, I'm still pretty confused how this works; I can't even test anything. The error that keeps coming up is `ReferenceError: io is not defined`. Some sites used something like `var io = require('socket.io');`. But then it results in the same error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I put the socket-lib folder in assets/www, where any other Javascript source should go. This is also where the index.html file is. Many sites use `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`, but this makes no sense to me. Many sites also imply the use of node.js, but I never see it anywhere.

How can I make this work?

**Reply edits:**

I tried it in Chrome, and it's giving me an `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` for the socket.io.js file. So I decide to source in require.js right before it. Then it gives the error `Uncaught Error: Module name "socket.io-client" has not been loaded yet for context`. Since I'm not using this, I care not. When I try the connection, though, it gives the same `io is not defined` error. When I define it as `var io = require('socket.io')`, the error is `Error: Module name "socket.io" has not been loaded yet for context: _ http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded`. I looked at the website, and it doesn't help me at all. When I try to put "require" as a function argument, another error occurs: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Comment: I found the answer, for anyone who gets immensely confused by the horrible lack of documentation of socket.io.

You cannot source "/socket-lib/socket.io.js"; you must source "http://yourwebsite.com:12345/socket.io/socket.io.js". The server automagically does the rest for you.

Comment: you are my new favorite person sir! Their samples on socket.io are horribly misleading.

Comment: According the documentation, since v1.0 you can request the client library from their CDN: http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#cdn-delivery

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I found the answer for anyone who gets immensely confused by the horrible lack of documentation of `socket.io`.

You cannot source `/socket-lib/socket.io.js`,

you must source `http://yourwebsite.com:12345/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

The server automatically does the rest for you.

Comment: And the port (12345) mentioned here is nothing but the port on which node is running with socket.io

Comment: I had forgot to create `VirtualHost` in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to point the port where my node server was running, in my case it was `<VirtualHost *:8000>...`

Comment: I was getting this error because of line this: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.min.js"></script>
was looking like nonsense, cause when I use in fresh html file - it was working, but then tried by parts - use php die() and start from beginning of the file - it was working until I my sockets script went after require.js lib. Eearlier it did not do any harm but maybe when node udpated something - it broke.

Comment: Why? This is a client side library, so why does it need to be loaded from the server which you are trying to connect to?  Connection params are in the connect method.

Comment: Because it needs to be loaded from somewhere; you can't expect a browser to automatically have it. In case you're confused about my situation, the website is on the server, so everything is loaded from there anyway.

Comment: @trust_words Perhaps something else may be wrong with your code? I haven't worked with socket.io in five years, so I can't help much, but I can suggest codebeautify.org/jsvalidate to attempt to find what may be wrong somewhere.

Comment: I opened a new directory, installed dependencies and it worked! Sometimes, it's just a bad installation...maybe a broken dependency (or permissions).

Comment: brooooo this is so helpful

Answer (score 6):

I solved it myself by changing index.html to import the socket io client from bower, first i installed the bower component:

```
 bower install socket.io-client
```

then i changed the reference in index.html to :

```
 <script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Or file could be found at  - lib/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js

Answer (score 3):

I managed to blunder through this, and squandered about an hour, on something that turned out to be a very basic error.

When an function is not defined? Such as " Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined ". Does that not mean that the function is getting "used" before it is "created"?

In the part of my HTML file, that "calls" the javaScript files, it ***looked*** like this :

```
<script src='./js/playerChatter.js'></script> <!-- this one calls io -->
<script src="http://localhost:2019/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script><!-- This Creates io -->
```

and i ***changed*** it to this

```
<script src="http://localhost:2019/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- This Creates  io -->
<script src='./js/playerChatter.js'></script> <!-- this on calls io -->
```

So now the item "io", whether it is an object or function... Is actually getting created before it is getting used :D

Have FUN!

Answer (score 2):

write server side code in socket.io.js file and try src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

When getting socket.io to work with many other libraries using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) I had same error, it turned out to be caused because of trying to load the socket.io.js file from the same /js folder than the rest of the other files.

Placing it in a separated folder, fixed it for me, you can see the **[code in this gist](https://gist.github.com/3651490)** but all I changed for making it work, was this:

instead of:

> socketio: 'socket.io',

Use:

> socketio: '../socket.io/socket.io',

Not sure about the reason of this behavior, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: Because of the folder structure of the installed socket.io package. It must point the to the root server folder then to the socket.io path

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using **Unity WebGL** with C# **UnitySocketIO** plugin, I need to add **delay** (1 sec) between Init and Connect, because the first method did not have time to add a new JS Socket object and code (listeners) to the page to work with it..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your browser cannot find the socket.io.js file. You could try opening the index.html on your computer with Firefox+Firebug or the Chrome Web Developer Tools and look at how the .js file is requested. On the other side, you could check the logs on the webserver serving the .js file whether there are any file not found errors.

The `require` function would be provided by e.g. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), but you would still need to configure the paths to your scripts correctly for it to work.

Comment: Do you have any other advice? I still can't get this to work.

Comment: Without actually seeing both your code and your directory structure, it's pretty hard to tell what is wrong. Maybe you could upload your progress so far somewhere?

Comment: All the code that is relevant is already posted. The problem persists when all other Javascript is taken away. As for the directory structure, it's in Eclipse SDK, and the project is HelloWorld. The file "index.html" and the folder "socket-lib" are both in "HelloWorld/assets/www". The only other important file (I think) would be the Java file: "HelloWorld/src/com.helloworld.helloworld/Hello.java". It was created by default; the only thing I did there was changing the `setContentView()` line to `super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`.

Answer (score 0):

For me after debugging through all of the very helpful suggestions, it turned out to be simply that my node server had stopped. I had been running it manually in a terminal window during dev.

Make sure your node [yourservercode].js is running on the specified port! :-]

Answer (score 0):

I use jspm.

Add this:

```
import 'btford/angular-socket-io/mock/socket-io';
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you have to use the complete URL.

`<script src="http://127.0.0.1:5565/socket.io/socket.io.js "></script>`

if it's giving you an error 404  please check whether io is properly instantiated on your server.js.If not please refer following to instantiate the io properly.

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

In your server.js

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http'); //from express module
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
```

Answer (score 0):

got to url `/socket.io/socket.io.js` and check if a js file is served or not if yes then instead of writing

```
var socket = io();
```

write

```
window.onload= function(){
var socket = io();
}
```